# rails 6 save data to multiple tables from one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still really new to rails.  I have a site that allows tournament directors to host online registration.  When they setup the registraiton form they can add custom fields for different section like basic info, division, etc.  That part is working but when the user goes to the registraiton form, I am able to pull the fields into the form but I don't know how to save them to a separate table.  I have a participants table and the custom fields are in a fields table.

When a user registers or edits their registraion info, how do I save the input for the custom fields into a separate table. I have a table called field_answers with participant_id, field_id and answer, but can't figure out how to save the answers from the participants_controler.

Below is the form for the basic section of the registraiton form.  The  @basic.each section is where the custom fields are being pulled in, and I'm guessing I'll need to give the fields unique names rather than just answer then save them but I don't know how to do that.

```
<%= form_with model: [@event, @participant], class: "shadow p-3 mb-3 rounded text-dark", local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :child_id, value: @cid %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @tID %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :basic_complete, value: 1 %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :first_name  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', value: @part.first_name, placeholder: "First name" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :last_name  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', value: @part.last_name, placeholder: "Last name" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :date_of_birth  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.date_field :dob, class: 'form-control', value: @part.dob, placeholder: "Date of Birth" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :gender  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <label class="main">Female
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, "female", checked: true if @part.gender == "female" %>
        <span class="w3docs"></span>
      </label>

      <label class="main">Male
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, "male", checked: true if @part.gender == "male" %>
        <span class="w3docs"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :address1  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :address1, class: 'form-control', value: @part.address1, placeholder: "Address 1" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :address2  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :address2, class: 'form-control', value: @part.address2, placeholder: "Address 2" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :city  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', value: @part.city, placeholder: "City" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :state  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control', value: @part.state, placeholder: "State" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :country  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :country, class: 'form-control', value: @part.country, placeholder: "Country" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :zip  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control', pattern: "[0-9]*", value: @part.zip, placeholder: "Postal Code" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :phone  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control', pattern: "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",  maxlength: "12", value: @part.phone, placeholder: "Phone" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <% @basic.each do |b| %>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label">
        <%= f.label b.name  %>:<span class="text-danger">*</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
        <%= f.text_field :answer, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :field_id, value: b.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @tID %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <%= f.submit "Register", class: "profile_btn" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my participants_controller.rb:

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :event
  before_action :participant, only: %i[create]
  
  def new
    @participant = @event.participants.new
    if current_user 
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      @children = @user.children
    end 
    @basic = Field.where(event_id: @event.id, field_type: 'basic')
  end

  def create
    byebug
    if @participant.save
      flash[:success] = 'Child was successfully created.'
      #redirect_to edit_event_participant_path(@participant.id)
      redirect_to "/events/#{@event.id}/participants/#{@participant.id}/edit?rt=#{@participant.child_id != nil ? 'child' : 'self'}&step=2"
    else
      byebug
      flash[:notice] = @participant.errors.full_messages.join('<br />').html_safe
      redirect_back(fallback_location: events_path)
    end
  end

  def show 
   
  end

  def edit 
    @participant = Participant.find(params[:id])
    @child = Child.find(@participant.child_id)
    @custom_basic = Field.find_by(event_id: @participant.event_id, field_type: 'basic')
  end

  def update
   
  end

  private

  def event
    @event = Event.find_by(id: params[:event_tourn_url])
  end

  def participant
    @participant = event.participants.new(participant_params)
  end

  def participant_params
    params.require(:participant).permit(:event_id, :user_id, :child_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :country, :zip, :phone, :basic_complete)
  end
end
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Edit:
I edited my participant_params in the controller to:

```
def participant_params
    params.require(:participant).permit(:event_id, :user_id, :child_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender,
                                        :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :country, :zip, :phone,
                                        participant_fields_attributes: [:id, :participant_id, :field_id, :answer])
  end
```

And my participants model is:

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :participant_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant_fields
```

When I submit all the correct fields are added to the participants table but nothing to the participant_fields table. And in the logs I get Unpermitted

```
parameters: :answer, :field_id
```

Comment: Can you paste your current controller code please

Comment: I added it to the post.  Thanks,

Comment: If the main form object has a `has_many :basics` relationship, you should be able to use `f.fields_for :basic do` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and let rails handle the uniq ids/names and the creation of the whole group of objects in different tables. https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: I tried that but get Unpermitted parameters: :answer, :field_id, everything else gets added to the participant table but nothing to the participant_fields table.  I edit the post so you can see it there.

Comment: Check the parameters coming over in your terminal. `participant_fields_attributes` is the normal way this would work, but it's possible they are coming over in some other way. 

FYI, Cocoon is a gem that handles nested attributes in a form, and GoRails has a [video](https://gorails.com/episodes/dynamic-nested-forms-with-stimulus-js) that shows you how to build it from scratch with StimulusJS.